# Istio getting 503 but traffic seems to make it to services/deployments, no errors in logs

Tags: istio

Been struggling to debug my mesh, no matter what I just keep getting 503 responses with the envoy response: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination. I'm new to Istio, but I've gone over my manifests many times and I'm highly confident there are no issues there. Looking at the envoy response online, it seems highly general. On the Kiali dashboard, I can see that traffic is making it to both the frontend and backend services/ deployments when I curl them:

[image: kiali traffic graph]

The logs for both the ingress gateway  and for the frontend pod's istio-proxy do not show any errors, or even the attempted traffic.

istio ingress-gateway

```
2024-01-10T17:39:28.641565Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T18:10:53.719147Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T18:41:29.693091Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T19:12:26.646182Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T19:44:18.914142Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T20:12:52.334833Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T20:45:56.577593Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T21:18:23.125076Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T21:47:26.439850Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T22:15:45.249214Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T22:45:34.134031Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T23:16:16.451706Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T23:45:59.830130Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T23:53:03.212381Z info    ads XDS: Incremental Pushing ConnectedEndpoints:2 Version:
2024-01-10T23:53:03.432305Z info    cache   generated new workload certificate  latency=218.593986ms ttl=23h59m59.567703166s
2024-01-11T00:13:54.894269Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T00:43:24.126057Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T01:16:00.603262Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T01:46:31.623950Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T02:14:44.812892Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T02:43:42.572133Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T03:13:07.989421Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T03:45:11.261123Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T04:13:26.980068Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T04:45:02.884599Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T05:15:48.321797Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T05:44:29.394873Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T06:15:44.027922Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T06:48:33.264475Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T07:16:08.424316Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T07:49:14.976548Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T08:21:20.356454Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T08:52:08.837400Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T09:23:35.157947Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T09:52:18.891569Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T10:25:24.520775Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T10:57:06.178684Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T11:27:04.456537Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T11:53:03.217755Z info    ads XDS: Incremental Pushing ConnectedEndpoints:2 Version:
2024-01-11T11:53:03.907326Z info    cache   generated new workload certificate  latency=688.642546ms ttl=23h59m59.092679619s
2024-01-11T11:56:05.290064Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T12:28:59.137331Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T13:00:07.386486Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T13:32:29.737739Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T14:04:06.735386Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T14:33:32.992460Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T15:01:30.692872Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T15:29:42.825974Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T15:59:49.910937Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T16:32:25.414335Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T17:05:30.562666Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T17:34:31.851721Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T18:02:56.767602Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T18:33:22.714776Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T19:05:28.874343Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T19:33:42.065152Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T20:01:19.836778Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T20:28:57.767072Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T21:01:00.282627Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T21:32:59.658689Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T22:05:10.396965Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T22:36:02.832397Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T23:05:10.608314Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T23:33:58.468536Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T23:53:03.454339Z info    ads XDS: Incremental Pushing ConnectedEndpoints:2 Version:
2024-01-11T23:53:03.562843Z info    cache   generated new workload certificate  latency=108.1021ms ttl=23h59m59.437162635s
2024-01-12T00:04:52.591259Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T00:34:18.255581Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T01:06:46.122216Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T01:39:34.027079Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T02:10:37.612683Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T02:38:24.955286Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T03:06:00.474704Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T03:38:02.690740Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T04:06:27.881326Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T04:39:33.418122Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T05:12:13.165695Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T05:44:39.058445Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T06:12:28.577711Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T06:42:03.268787Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T07:13:45.529436Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T07:41:05.009951Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T08:08:59.016262Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T08:41:16.783084Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T09:12:31.367675Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T09:42:57.325226Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T10:11:32.819091Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T10:39:18.690768Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T11:06:45.377081Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T11:38:33.660663Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T11:53:03.282142Z info    ads XDS: Incremental Pushing ConnectedEndpoints:2 Version:
2024-01-12T11:53:03.678582Z info    cache   generated new workload certificate  latency=396.146192ms ttl=23h59m59.321423077s
2024-01-12T12:07:11.832187Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T12:35:05.222401Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T13:03:37.238256Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T13:34:01.490874Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T14:06:53.709358Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T14:34:52.188384Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T15:05:33.768216Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T15:35:52.800323Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T16:05:10.832043Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T16:35:27.406885Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T17:08:12.322546Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T17:36:46.004417Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T18:04:10.378603Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T18:35:42.737748Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T19:03:31.836841Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T19:34:59.937562Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T20:08:06.743835Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T20:36:41.221091Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
```

frontend pod's istio-proxy:

```
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353818Z info    FLAG: --concurrency="0"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353877Z info    FLAG: --domain="demoapp.svc.cluster.local"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353892Z info    FLAG: --help="false"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353897Z info    FLAG: --log_as_json="false"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353902Z info    FLAG: --log_caller=""
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353908Z info    FLAG: --log_output_level="default:info"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353918Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate=""
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353924Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_age="30"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353930Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_backups="1000"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353936Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_size="104857600"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353958Z info    FLAG: --log_stacktrace_level="default:none"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353981Z info    FLAG: --log_target="[stdout]"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353987Z info    FLAG: --meshConfig="./etc/istio/config/mesh"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353993Z info    FLAG: --outlierLogPath=""
2024-01-11T23:18:13.353997Z info    FLAG: --profiling="true"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.354005Z info    FLAG: --proxyComponentLogLevel="misc:error"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.354010Z info    FLAG: --proxyLogLevel="warning"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.354015Z info    FLAG: --serviceCluster="istio-proxy"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.354020Z info    FLAG: --stsPort="0"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.354025Z info    FLAG: --templateFile=""
2024-01-11T23:18:13.354036Z info    FLAG: --tokenManagerPlugin="GoogleTokenExchange"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.354047Z info    FLAG: --vklog="0"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.354072Z info    Version 1.20.1-552626bd81f625917bcba6e415cae5aa3d5c61af-Clean
2024-01-11T23:18:13.358823Z info    Maximum file descriptors (ulimit -n): 1048576
2024-01-11T23:18:13.359114Z info    Proxy role  ips=[10.24.1.52] type=sidecar id=frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp domain=demoapp.svc.cluster.local
2024-01-11T23:18:13.359239Z info    Apply proxy config from env {}

2024-01-11T23:18:13.362214Z info    cpu limit detected as 2, setting concurrency
2024-01-11T23:18:13.362815Z info    Effective config: binaryPath: /usr/local/bin/envoy
concurrency: 2
configPath: ./etc/istio/proxy
controlPlaneAuthPolicy: MUTUAL_TLS
discoveryAddress: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
drainDuration: 45s
proxyAdminPort: 15000
serviceCluster: istio-proxy
statNameLength: 189
statusPort: 15020
terminationDrainDuration: 5s
tracing:
  zipkin:
    address: zipkin.istio-system:9411

2024-01-11T23:18:13.362858Z info    JWT policy is third-party-jwt
2024-01-11T23:18:13.362863Z info    using credential fetcher of JWT type in cluster.local trust domain
2024-01-11T23:18:13.364762Z info    platform detected is GCP
2024-01-11T23:18:13.366740Z info    Workload SDS socket not found. Starting Istio SDS Server
2024-01-11T23:18:13.367044Z info    CA Endpoint istiod.istio-system.svc:15012, provider Citadel
2024-01-11T23:18:13.366903Z info    Opening status port 15020
2024-01-11T23:18:13.367235Z info    Using CA istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 cert with certs: var/run/secrets/istio/root-cert.pem
2024-01-11T23:18:13.402717Z info    ads All caches have been synced up in 49.832101ms, marking server ready
2024-01-11T23:18:13.409425Z info    xdsproxy    Initializing with upstream address "istiod.istio-system.svc:15012" and cluster "Kubernetes"
2024-01-11T23:18:13.410496Z info    sds Starting SDS grpc server
2024-01-11T23:18:13.412350Z info    starting Http service at 127.0.0.1:15004
2024-01-11T23:18:13.419583Z info    Pilot SAN: [istiod.istio-system.svc]
2024-01-11T23:18:13.423482Z info    Starting proxy agent
2024-01-11T23:18:13.423507Z info    starting
2024-01-11T23:18:13.423573Z info    Envoy command: [-c etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev.json --drain-time-s 45 --drain-strategy immediate --local-address-ip-version v4 --file-flush-interval-msec 1000 --disable-hot-restart --allow-unknown-static-fields --log-format %Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ   %l  envoy %n %g:%#  %v  thread=%t -l warning --component-log-level misc:error --concurrency 2]
2024-01-11T23:18:13.568809Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-11T23:18:13.626424Z info    ads ADS: new connection for node:frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp-1
2024-01-11T23:18:13.628095Z info    ads ADS: new connection for node:frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp-2
2024-01-11T23:18:13.692578Z info    cache   generated new workload certificate  latency=289.249861ms ttl=23h59m59.307427291s
2024-01-11T23:18:13.692829Z info    cache   Root cert has changed, start rotating root cert
2024-01-11T23:18:13.692996Z info    ads XDS: Incremental Pushing ConnectedEndpoints:2 Version:
2024-01-11T23:18:13.693205Z info    cache   returned workload certificate from cache    ttl=23h59m59.306798059s
2024-01-11T23:18:13.693870Z info    ads SDS: PUSH request for node:frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp resources:1 size:4.0kB resource:default
2024-01-11T23:18:13.693949Z info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache   ttl=23h59m59.306055017s
2024-01-11T23:18:13.693220Z info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache   ttl=23h59m59.306782521s
2024-01-11T23:18:13.694212Z info    ads SDS: PUSH request for node:frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp resources:1 size:1.1kB resource:ROOTCA
2024-01-11T23:18:13.694330Z info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache   ttl=23h59m59.305674136s
2024-01-11T23:18:13.924092Z info    Readiness succeeded in 588.543248ms
2024-01-11T23:18:13.924910Z info    Envoy proxy is ready
2024-01-11T23:51:14.729921Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T00:21:26.031687Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T00:52:25.434945Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T01:25:03.575424Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T01:53:40.462664Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T02:24:47.911598Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T02:57:26.960519Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T03:25:23.798840Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T03:54:12.250484Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T04:23:03.958156Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T04:52:17.383375Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T05:19:49.355841Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T05:52:29.846325Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T06:19:41.188037Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T06:52:41.638570Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T07:23:47.199477Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T07:54:05.093512Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T08:24:18.470351Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T08:55:30.738326Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T09:23:29.840299Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T09:56:24.048021Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T10:25:56.005971Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T10:53:41.065764Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T11:18:13.347744Z info    ads XDS: Incremental Pushing ConnectedEndpoints:2 Version:
2024-01-12T11:18:13.479834Z info    cache   generated new workload certificate  latency=130.434033ms ttl=23h59m59.520168857s
2024-01-12T11:21:47.474906Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T11:50:33.461539Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T12:23:13.155577Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T12:51:52.531204Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T13:24:06.489716Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T13:53:11.813329Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T14:24:07.889602Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T14:57:14.117992Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T15:27:19.081699Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T15:57:05.269909Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T16:25:17.971083Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T16:57:28.123603Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T17:29:26.398478Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T18:02:24.213613Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T18:31:40.738776Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T19:00:50.328261Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T19:28:30.866135Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T19:59:35.794552Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T20:30:13.337932Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-12T20:58:59.642126Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
```

istioctl analyze and verify-install show no errors.

istioctl proxy-status on the ingress gateway, frontend, and backend pods, along with using x describe show no errors:

```
$ istioctl ps istio-egressgateway-5978d8c44b-rbnmf.istio-system
Clusters Match
Listeners Match
Routes Match

$ istioctl x describe pod istio-ingressgateway-6d6469f44-ckddk.istio-system 
Pod: istio-ingressgateway-6d6469f44-ckddk.istio-system
   Pod Revision: default
   Pod Ports: 15021 (istio-proxy), 8080 (istio-proxy), 8443 (istio-proxy), 15090 (istio-proxy)
   WARNING: User ID (UID) 1337 is reserved for the sidecar proxy.
--------------------
Service: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system
   Port: status-port 15021/UnsupportedProtocol targets pod port 15021
   Port: http2 80/HTTP2 targets pod port 8080
   Port: https 443/HTTPS targets pod port 8443
--------------------
Effective PeerAuthentication:
   Workload mTLS mode: PERMISSIVE

$ istioctl ps frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp
Clusters Match
Listeners Match
Routes Match (RDS last loaded at Thu, 11 Jan 2024 15:18:13 PST)

$ istioctl x describe frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp
Error: unknown resource type "frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp"

$ istioctl x describe pod frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp
Pod: frontend-deploy-5dbdf8cbb9-q48dc.demoapp
   Pod Revision: default
   Pod Ports: 15090 (istio-proxy), 3001 (frontend)
--------------------
Service: frontend-svc.demoapp
   Port: tcp-app-frontend 3001/TCP targets pod port 3001
--------------------
Effective PeerAuthentication:
   Workload mTLS mode: PERMISSIVE


Exposed on Ingress Gateway http://35.236.49.16
VirtualService: vert-serv-from-gw.demoapp
   Match: /*
   1 additional destination(s) that will not reach this pod

$ istioctl x describe service frontend-svc.demoapp 
Service: frontend-svc.demoapp
   Port: tcp-app-frontend 3001/TCP targets pod port 3001


Exposed on Ingress Gateway http://35.236.49.16
VirtualService: vert-serv-from-gw.demoapp
   Match: /*
   1 additional destination(s) that will not reach this pod

$ istioctl ps backend-deploy-6d7fb86486-nmq6k.demoapp 
Clusters Match
Listeners Match
Routes Match (RDS last loaded at Thu, 11 Jan 2024 15:18:13 PST)

$ istioctl x describe pod backend-deploy-6d7fb86486-nmq6k.demoapp 
Pod: backend-deploy-6d7fb86486-nmq6k.demoapp
   Pod Revision: default
   Pod Ports: 15090 (istio-proxy), 5001 (backend)
--------------------
Service: backend-svc.demoapp
   Port: tcp-app-backend 5001/TCP targets pod port 5001
--------------------
Effective PeerAuthentication:
   Workload mTLS mode: PERMISSIVE


Exposed on Ingress Gateway http://35.236.49.16
VirtualService: vert-serv-from-gw.demoapp
   Match: /api*
   1 additional destination(s) that will not reach this pod

istioctl x describe service backend-svc.demoapp 
Service: backend-svc.demoapp
   Port: tcp-app-backend 5001/TCP targets pod port 5001


Exposed on Ingress Gateway http://35.236.49.16
VirtualService: vert-serv-from-gw.demoapp
   Match: /api*
   1 additional destination(s) that will not reach this pod
```

I've been at this for too long with the time I've had available over the last month, even deleted the cluster and restarted a couple of times. I'm assuming theres something I've missed, but just cannot figure it out. If anyone has any suggestions of where else to look or how to further debug, I'm all ears. Thanks